# Proportion test under the null hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, proportion

In the code below, two binomial responses are simulated with the **same probability of success ($H_0$)** and the p-value of the 1-sided z-test is stored. This is repeated 10000 times.

```
n0  <- 100
n1  <- 100
pi0 <- 0.4
pi1 <- 0.4

pvals <- sapply(1:1e4, FUN = function(i) {
  
  y0 <- rbinom(n = 1, size = n0, prob = pi0)
  y1 <- rbinom(n = 1, size = n1, prob = pi1)
  
  tbl <- data.frame(
    success = c(y0, y1),
    failure = c(n0 - y0, n1 - y1))
  
  ptest <- prop.test(
    x           = as.matrix(tbl),
    alternative = "less",
    correct     = FALSE)
  
  ptest$p.value
  
})
```

I was expecting a uniform distribution of the p-values.

But...

[image]

When `correct = TRUE`, I got

[image]

**Can you explain me this strange behaviour?**

Comment: This seems to be an issue with poor p-value coverage stemming from the limited number of distinct cases with n0, n1= 100 (you only get a few hundred distinct p-values in ten thousand trials, you can see this if you increase the number of buckets in the histogram). If you set n0, n1 = 10000 instead, the issue disappears.

Comment: Indeed, there are only few hundred distinct p-values. I did not expect that... How come?

Comment: It has to do with the discrete nature of the table being tested. As you move one count from successes to failures or vice versa, the p-value takes a discrete jump. There are a finite number of ways to allocate a fixed number of counts in the contingency table, therefore a finite number of p-values that can be generated from that table. The vast majority of the tables in this instance will have between 25 and 55 successes - we're seeing the same contingency table and p-value many times. This isn't so much a problem with larger n0, n1, since more counts mean more distinct tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compute all possible p-values for a 2x2 table where each row is constrained to sum up to 100, you have $101^2$ different hypothetical tables. In addition, many of these tables mirror another one, so you end up with an even more restricted number of p-values, which you restrict even more by generating tables with proportion of successes concentrated near 0.4.

Without considering any particular success generating process, you only have 4964 possible p-values:

```
possible.p.values = c()
n=100
for (i in 0:n) {
  for (j in 0:n) {
    tab = rbind(c(i, n-i),
                c(j, n-j))
    res = prop.test(tab, alternative="less", correct=F)
    possible.p.values = c(possible.p.values, res$p.value) 
  
  }
}
length(unique(possible.p.values))
4964
```

If on the top of that you generate tables where successes are concentrated near a proportion of 0.4, so you restrict even further the number of possible p-values.  At best, your 10,000 simulations may be probably able to get only a few hundreds different p-values. (With your code and a seed set to 0, I get 695 different p-values).

To see that the number of possible p-values is quite restricted in your configuration, you can increase the number of bins of your histogram of p-values:

```
hist(pvals, breaks = 100)
```

[image: Histogram showing the scattered distribution of p values]

If you increase your number of n0 and n1, you'll give more "opportunities" to your simulated tables to get p-values farther from 0.5, which eventually will make your distribution look more uniform.

With 100,000 observations in each row:

```
n0  <- 100000
n1  <- 100000
pi0 <- 0.4
pi1 <- 0.4
set.seed(0)
pvals <- sapply(1:1e4, FUN = function(i) {
  
  y0 <- rbinom(n = 1, size = n0, prob = pi0)
  y1 <- rbinom(n = 1, size = n1, prob = pi1)
  
  tbl <- data.frame(
    success = c(y0, y1),
    failure = c(n0 - y0, n1 - y1))
  
  ptest <- prop.test(
    x           = as.matrix(tbl),
    alternative = "less",
    correct     = FALSE)
  
  ptest$p.value
  
})
hist(pvals)
```

[image: Histogram of p-values showing a much more uniform distribution]